# How do I store (file/data structure) voice commands and the responses in a voice command recognition program for speed?

Tags: python, database, data-structures, automation, voice-recognition

I've been building a Python voice program to automate development tasks like git, etc. Right now, I have all the responses in a `if command in audio_sample:` statement so needless to say it's getting lengthy. How do companies like Google and Amazon store their voice commands to make it fast? I initially thought of having a dictionary of commands as keys and responses/function calls as values. Also databases are a possibility. 
I'm looking to keep the program fast and light on memory and so it doesn't have hundreds or thousands of `if` statements to loop through every time a I make a voice command.

Comment: That question is too broad to answer. Please look at some implementations of NLP (natural language processing) toolkits and see how they are doing it.

Comment: https://www.nltk.org/

Comment: https://towardsdatascience.com/gentle-start-to-natural-language-processing-using-python-6e46c07addf3

Comment: In general, avoid `for` loops in Python, for your task you don't need them anyway. If you really want to set up  something from scratch for learning split the code in a module that just does fast language processing and a dictionary where you store commands with a key, e.g. `{'open': 'shell command here'}`. The `open` is something that your NLP delivers.

Comment: Joe, you're not wrong. I just didn't really know what questions to ask about storing them and was looking for a place to start. But thank you for your response. That gives me a direction to head towards. I figured storing them in dictionaries would work.

Comment: If that already solved your problem, please close the question and open a new one for a more specific question.